# An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.tag'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity code for a game that is suppose to follow the character if the gameobject tag name is "Player". But i am getting a code error and I dont know how to fix it.

***Error***

```
Assets/Script/CameraRunner.cs(10,32): error CS0120: An object reference   
is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.tag'
```

***Script***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraRunner : MonoBehaviour {



void FixedUpdate () 
{
    if (GameObject.tag == "Player") {
                    transform.position = new Vector3 (0, transform.position.y + 9f, -10);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in camera SmoothFollow.js script or iTween? Both do the desired and you only have to modify it slightly. iTween is ubiquitous.

Comment: Also are you attaching the script to the Main Camera, your desired object? Where are you attaching this script to, if it's assigned to the Camera, then GameObject is local, it only detects if the local object is tagged as Player. If it's on the player, then the position for the object is being changed. There is a lot wrong to the script, especially without enough information to formulate a proper response.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `gameObject.tag` instead of `GameObject.tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the built in camera SmoothFollow.js script or iTween? Both do the desired and you only have to modify it slightly. iTween is ubiquitous.

Also are you attaching the script to the Main Camera, your desired object? Where are you attaching this script to, if it's assigned to the Camera, then GameObject is local, it only detects if the local object is tagged as Player. If it's on the player, then the position for the object is being changed. There is a lot wrong to the script, especially without enough information to formulate a proper response.

In the script to fix it do the following and attach it to your camera. Also don't forget to set your player variable and set your tags if you don't do that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraRunner : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject player;

  void Start () {
    if (player == null)
      player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
  }

  void FixedUpdate () {
    if (player != null)
    transform.position = new Vector3 (0, player.transform.position.y + 9f, -10);
  }

}
```